# Get method for the name used in TextureAtlas to create Sprite

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a class that creates sprites using this constructor:

```
private Sprite sprite;
public Terrain(Sprite sprite) {
        this.Sprite = sprite;
}
```

I put these terrain sprites into a 2d array like this:

```
TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas("atlas.pack");
tiles[0][0] = new Terrain(atlas.createSprite("road");
tiles[0][1] = new Terrain(atlas.createSprite("grass");
[...]
```

I also have a Player class that walks around on my board and the position of the player is stored in the class. I would like to have a method in my terrain class that returns which type of Terrain it is, for example "road" or "grass". I want to do this so the player behaves differently depending on what piece of terrain he is standing on and moving to.

Is it possible to do this with the code I have?
I did consider just extending my constructor and add another string that is the same as the texture used but I figured there might be an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could just create an "TerrainType" attribute for your Terrain class, something like:

```
private Sprite sprite;
private TerrainType terrainType;
public Terrain(Sprite sprite, TerrainType terrainType) {
        this.sprite = sprite;
        this.terrainType = terrainType;
}
```

where the TerrainType could be an enum:

```
enum TerrainType {
    GRASS, ROAD;
}
```

and then instantiate your TerrainType like this:

```
new Terrain(atlas.createSprite("road"), TerrainType.ROAD);
```